# Arguments of OpenIE for extracting fewer event triples

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, information-retrieval, information-extraction, language-model

I'm new to NLP and I'm trying to using OpenIE to extract event triples from texts.

I looked into its documents but quite don't understand its arguments. For example, `max_entailments_per_clause` controls the maximum number of entailments to produce for each clause extracted in the sentence. What is entailment here? And `ignore_affinity` controls whether to ignore the affinity model for prepositional attachments. What is affinity here?

My question is, I try to use OpenIE to extract event triples from news headlines, but the triples might overlap. For example, the headline is "U.S. stock index futures points to higher start", the event triples extracted from OpenIE are `[('U.S. stock index futures', 'points to', 'start'), ('U.S. stock index futures', 'points to', 'higher start')]`. But they are quite overlapping and I only want the one without modifier (`('U.S. stock index futures', 'points to', 'start')` in this case). What should I do? What arguments should I use?